# inserting divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following code that i was hoping would allow me to click a button and add another box to the page but inj stread it just resets the page every time i click one of the buttons

```
<style>
    div.box 
    { 
        width: 50px; 
        height: 50px; 
        background-image: url("Images/smallBox.jpg"); 
    }

    div.largeBox 
    { 
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px; 
        background-image: url("Images/largeBox.jpg");
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setupDragging();
    });
    function setupDragging() {
        $(".box").draggable({ snap: true });
        $(".largeBox").draggable({ snap: true });
    }
    function addSmallBox() {
        var boxArea = document.getElementById('boxArea');
        var newBox = document.createElement('div');
        newBox.setAttribute('class', 'box');
        boxArea.appendChild(newBox);
        setupDragging();
    }
    function addLargeBox() {
        var boxArea = document.getElementById('boxArea');
        var newBox = document.createElement('div');
        newBox.setAttribute('class', 'largeBox');
        boxArea.appendChild(newBox);
        setupDragging();
    }
</script>
<form>
<button onclick="addSmallBox();">small box</button>
<button onclick="addLargeBox();">large box</button>
</form>

<div id="boxArea">
</div>
```

please can somebody let me know what i am doing wrong and how i can achieve what i want.

**ANSWER:**

just an update on the final result

```
    <style>
    div.box 
    { 
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-image: url("../Images/smallBox.jpg");
        position: absolute;
    }

    div.largeBox 
    { 
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: url("../Images/largeBox.jpg");
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setupDragging();
        $('.addBox').click(function(e){
        if($(this).hasClass('smallBox')) addSmallBox();
        else if($(this).hasClass('largeBox')) addLargeBox();
        e.preventDefault();
        })
    });
    function setupDragging() {
        $(".box").draggable({ snap: true });
        $(".largeBox").draggable({ snap: true });
    }
    function addSmallBox() {
        $('<div>', { class: 'box' }).appendTo('#boxArea')
        setupDragging();
    }
    function addLargeBox() {
        $('<div>', { class: 'largeBox' }).appendTo('#boxArea')
        setupDragging();
    }
</script>
<form>
<button class='addBox smallBox'>small box</button>
<button class='addBox largeBox'>large box</button>
</form>

<div id="boxArea">
</div>
```

i made use of several of the answers below and this was the final result but went down the html5 route in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are using jQuery, if I were you, I would not use the onclick attribute in your button.  Instead, add an event listener like so:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  addLargeBox();
  return false;
});
```

OR

```
$('button').click(function(e){
  addLargeBox();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Both of which will prevent the user's browser from following the link but will execute the JavaScript as you want.

Also, since you require two different functions to be executed depending on which button is clicked, you should probably add a class or id to differentiate the two.

Your markup would then look like this:

```
<button class="add-box">small box</button>
<button class="add-box large-box">large box</button>
```

And your JavaScript would be:

```
$('.add-box').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('large-box')) addLargeBox();
  else addSmallBox();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Well, why even create `addLargeBox()`, set up everything in the anonymous function, I hope thats possible, m not a JS/jQuery ninja

Comment: Because he may want to call that function from other events, and if he left it in the anonymous function, he'd have to get into the copypasta game.  Always best to keep code DRY.  In fact, his code could be simplified further, but I concentrated on answering his original question.  For example, addLargeBox() and addSmallBox() could be combined into one function addBox(boxSize).

Comment: DRY, right said fred, yes the code can be improved further :-)

Answer (score 1):

The button tag you are using is a [HTML5 version of a form submit button](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_button.asp) which causes a page refresh.
Change the buttons to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="addSmallBox();" value="small box" />
```

Or put `return false` at the bottom of each of your javascript functions.

Comment: and in fact as suggested by @brad, bind the method to element instead of onclick, Google unobtrusive javascript and you will find how tos on it

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. **Always** separate JS from code (that means lose the onclick attributes and bind them in javascript instead.)
2. The form is still being submitted; have your functions return false/preventDefault (jQuery) to avoid this.

Some hints:

1. Since you're already using jQuery, why not build html elements with it? (`$('<div>',{class:'box'}).appendTo('#boxArea')` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You have to return false from the click event to prevent the default browser behavior of following the link.

Comment: as in `function addSmallBox() {
         var boxArea = document.getElementById('boxArea');
         var newBox = document.createElement('div');
         newBox.setAttribute('class', 'box');
         boxArea.appendChild(newBox);
         setupDragging();
            return false;
     }` ?

Comment: am not a jQuery Ninja but am sure there must be some sort of param that can be used to prevent default action of an html element

Comment: just found there is `event.preventDefault()` for events, if I had done this, I would have binded the onclick event for this element and used `event.preventDefault()`, have used it in YUI3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why just by glancing at the code, but perhaps you could try retrieving the boxArea.InnerHTML, appending the appropriate HTML string to it, and setting the boxArea.InnerHTML to the result.

Something like:

boxArea.InnerHTML = boxArea.InnerHTML + "<div class='largeBox'></div>";